# Ungrouping values in same column into new lines

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to separate cases where there are more than 1 responsible in a line. Then I would create a line for each of them, getting their respectives id's and weights, and keeping the other columns with the same values of the original table.

Basically I want to convert this table:

| goal_id | goal_name | owner | person_id | person_name | responsible_id | responsible_name | responsible_weight |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 65 | Goal 111 | Jade | 137, 248, 544, 910 | Robert, Bruce, James, Oliver | 1033 | Jade | 25 |
| 72 | Goal 222 | Drake | 377 | Frank | 15 | Drake | 10 |
| 39 | Goal 333 | Jimmy | 72 | Luke | 49, 421 | Brandon, Jimmy | 30; 45 |
| 101 | Goal 123 | Michael | 13, 22 | Washington, Andrew | 191, 1033, 248 | Michael, Jade, Bruce | 10; 10; 50 |

Into this table:

| goal_id | goal_name | owner | person_id | person_name | responsible_id | responsible_name | responsible_weight |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 65 | Goal 111 | Jade | 137, 248, 544, 910 | Robert, Bruce, James, Oliver | 1033 | Jade | 25 |
| 72 | Goal 222 | Drake | 377 | Frank | 15 | Drake | 10 |
| 39 | Goal 333 | Jimmy | 72 | Luke | 49 | Brandon | 30 |
| 39 | Goal 333 | Jimmy | 72 | Luke | 421 | Jimmy | 45 |
| 101 | Goal 123 | Michael | 13, 22 | Washington, Andrew | 191 | Michael | 10 |
| 101 | Goal 123 | Michael | 13, 22 | Washington, Andrew | 1033 | Jade | 10 |
| 101 | Goal 123 | Michael | 13, 22 | Washington, Andrew | 248 | Bruce | 50 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can combine [`Series.str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and [`DataFrame.explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) to  split the strings in the "responsible_*" columns and create duplicate rows for these entries. Once we have those, we connect them to the rest of the original df using [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) on `axis=1`. This will fit all the (duplicated) indices together.

```
# get cols that start with "resonsible"
cols_splits = [col for col in df.columns if col.startswith('responsible')]

# list comprehension with split on ", " or "; " (necessary for "responsible_weight") 
# to get 3x pd.Series()
splits = [df[col].astype(str).str.split(', |; ', regex=True).explode() for col in cols_splits]

# index will be [0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3] for each series

# now, we want to concatenate the "unexploded" cols from the original df 
# with these 3 series.

# slice with all unexploded cols
unexploded_df = df.iloc[:,~df.columns.isin(cols_splits)]

# concat
new_df = pd.concat([unexploded_df,*splits], axis=1)

print(new_df)

   goal_id goal_name    owner           person_id  \
0       65  Goal 111     Jade  137, 248, 544, 910   
1       72  Goal 222    Drake                 377   
2       39  Goal 333    Jimmy                  72   
2       39  Goal 333    Jimmy                  72   
3      101  Goal 123  Michael              13, 22   
3      101  Goal 123  Michael              13, 22   
3      101  Goal 123  Michael              13, 22   

                    person_name responsible_id responsible_name  \
0  Robert, Bruce, James, Oliver           1033             Jade   
1                         Frank             15            Drake   
2                          Luke             49          Brandon   
2                          Luke            421            Jimmy   
3            Washington, Andrew            191          Michael   
3            Washington, Andrew           1033             Jade   
3            Washington, Andrew            248            Bruce   

  responsible_weight  
0                 25  
1                 10  
2                 30  
2                 45  
3                 10  
3                 10  
3                 50
```

Comment: I tried your code and it almost got there. But the "splits" returns some NaN's in lines that don't have ", " or "; ". Don't know why isn't working properly.

Comment: Curious. Could you give an example or two of lines where this is happening. Please specify the column name(s), original value and the result (is the result 1 or multiple rows?).

Comment: The first two rows, that don't have anything to split. Happened in responsible_id and responsible_weight for Jade and Drake. I realized that works well if I add .astype(str) before the .str.split. That solved.

Comment: Ah, I see. I assumed (...) that the vals in those cols would all be strings already. Also interesting that `.str.split()` produces NaNs for the `int`s. If all vals in the cols were `int` , you would have gotten an `AttributeError`. Anyway, glad you've found the solution. I've updated the answer with `astype(str)`. If we're good to go now, you could close the question by accepting the answer.